# Yii2 composer vendor

Tags: yii2, composer-php, vendor

I've modified some files in one of vendor package and I know git will not commit those changes.

What would be the best approach to commit my change? Move Package out of vendor?

If I run composer update, I believe my updated code will be reverted?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: can you pls put package name here and some code what does you change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes when you run `composer update` your changes will be reverted.

Use `git add /vendor/package/editedfile.php`, full path of file to upload live.

But keep in mind this is not pure solution ;)

Comment: so i guess the only solution is move the code outta vendor and push to git?

Comment: Yeah, you can do this.

Comment: You can create component and include your required library there. more about [Yii2 Component Wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/)